# Cut Video with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cut

I have a video 20 muminute long time, I want to cut the first 5 minutes and 5 minutes of video finally. I have to use commands like, can help me?

I user commant here: **`ffmpeg -ss [start_seconds] -i [input_file] -t [duration_seconds] [outputfile]`** . But I think it is not right.

[illustrating images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UvKI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut out first 5 and last 5 minutes, use

```
ffmpeg -ss 300 -t 609 -i input -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero output
```

Depending on location of keyframes, the cutpoints won't be precise. If you skip the `-c copy`, it will transcode, which will be a precise cut.

Comment: I only want video between and can only use a command not ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, read the Q too quickly. Corrected.